# Cant figure out how get the last line of the rectangle to work

Tags: java

I have an exercise within my course that asks us to build a program that makes a rectangle made of "*" with the middle being empty. I know I am close as my code almost prints it but it does not produce a full rectangle

any ideas?

```
/**
 * Week 4, Exercise 7.
 * @author INSERT YOUR NAME HERE
 */

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Exercise7 {
    
    static Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        
        int height ;
        int length;
        
        System.out.println("what is the height of the rectangle");
        height = Scan.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("what is the legnth of the rectangle");
        length = Scan.nextInt();
        
        
        for (int row = 1; row <= height; row ++) {
            
            for (int col=1; col<= length; col ++) {
                
                if (col==1 || row == 1 || col == height || row == length) {
                
                System.out.print("* ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                };
                
                
            };
            
            System.out.println();
            
        };
        
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Replace `if (col==1 || row == 1 || col == height || row == length)`  with `if (col==1 || row == 1 || col == length || row == height)`  2. Remove the Blank in `"* "` or add a Blank in `" "`